# updating drivers right after Ubuntu installation

Tags: drivers

I'm a newby to ubuntu but i wanted to try it on one of my extra laptops, and I seen i'll have to update drivers for wifi card, etc.  I was curious if i could download a program to do so, or if i just have to do it manually.

Also if there's some ubuntu for dummies pdf. guide or something for beginners that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the driver manager program; you can find it by typing Additional Drivers into the search dash.
Regarding pdf guides for ubuntu I've found one at http://files.ubuntu-manual.org/manuals/getting-started-with-ubuntu/16.04/en_US/screen/Getting%20Started%20with%20Ubuntu%2016.04.pdf .

All the best.